# jQuery Ajax post request stuck on pending on Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome

I've got a jQuery client making an Ajax post request to a Spring Controller.
On the server side, no error has been logged.
On the client side, the request is stuck on pending a very long time, minutes, then might fail either with ERR_SPDY_PROTOCOL_ERROR or ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED.

This problem is reproducible on Chrome, but not on Firefox. Verified affected version is 70.0.3538.77, there may be others too.
Also, the problem occurs on a specific deployment of the application and not elsewhere, development or production.

The client sends HTTPS 2 requests on that environment. On the development environment it is HTTP 1.1. On the server, all requests are recorded as 1.1.

For no apparent reason, the requests started going through, but this is a recurring problem and would like to solve it.
Since the problem started happening, I can't reproduce it and check if the problem is too many connections to the server (more than 6).
I use three DNS servers, the last one of which is Google's 8.8.8.8.

I am looking for a code fix or a hint whether this could be related to server setup. 
I am almost certain that it is a combination of client code and networking.

What the problem is not:

- Antivirus ([Chrome net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29894154/chrome-neterr-incomplete-chunked-encoding-error))
- Prediction service related ([Stalled and pending ajax requests by JQuery in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28010156/stalled-and-pending-ajax-requests-by-jquery-in-chrome)) - the comment about proxy and connections seems more relevant though.
- Ad-blocker extension / plug-in ([Failed to load resource under Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4390134/failed-to-load-resource-under-chrome))

What I've tried unsuccessfully:

- https://www.reddit.com/r/chrome/comments/3ej5ua/err_spdy_protocol_error/
- https://www.itechgyan.com/err_spdy_protocol_error/
- [jQuery Ajax requests are getting cancelled without being sent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7577275/jquery-ajax-requests-are-getting-cancelled-without-being-sent)

What doesn't answer the question:

- [Ajax request over https hangs for 40 seconds in chrome only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14821725/ajax-request-over-https-hangs-for-40-seconds-in-chrome-only)

On the client side, I've tried clearing browser data, flushing sockets and private browsing / incognito.

The only thing that sometimes, rarely, bypasses the error is going on incognito and flushing sockets and emptying cache from chrome://net-internals/#events

```
var formData = new FormData();

formData.append( /* ... */ );

//...

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/somepath/update",
    cache: false,
    data: formData,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function(result) {
        //...
    },
    fail: function(result) {
        //....
    },
    error: function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ){
        alert(textStatus + ":" + errorThrown);
    }
});
```

A separate request using $.post was going through:

```
$.post("someotherpath/update", $("#someForm").serialize())
    .done(function (data) {
        //...
     })
     .fail(function (data) {
         //...
     })
     .always(function () {
         //...
     });
```

Server side:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/somepath/update", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json;charset=UTF-8")
public @ResponseBody String update(ModelClass model) {
    JSONObject result = new JSONObject();
    //...
    return result.toString();
}
```

If it's relevant, there are the following filters. I'm afraid I can't post more of them at the moment:

```
@Configurable
public class Filter1 extends OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter implements Filter{

    public void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest httpReq, HttpServletResponse httpResp, FilterChain chain)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
        //...
    }
}


@Configurable
public class Filter2 extends OncePerRequestFilter implements Filter{

    public void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest httpReq, HttpServletResponse httpResp, FilterChain chain)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
        //...
    }
}

@Order(/* very small integer */)
public class Filter3 extends OncePerRequestFilter {

}
```

Expected result is that the code should go through the success callback.
Instead the request is stuck on pending for minutes, then enters the error callback.

Comment: And your jquery version is...? :D And have you tried using postman or curl to send a basic request to confirm the server is responding OK to the same type of request?

Comment: Thanks for your comment @CodyG. Version is 1.7.2. I haven't tried postman, but I would guess that trying with Firefox is enough.

Comment: Have you tried an updated version of jquery or setting a timeout on the ajax request?  The point of trying it with another application is to separate the issue with the library or your server. ... or with the client.

Comment: I will see if I can upgrade jQuery. I understand why it is important to try with another application/client.

Comment: Could this be improved with an asynchronous request and the use of a Promise?

Comment: Something to consider: I've had various problems because I turned on a flag in chrome://flags/. The flag `experimental web platform features` turns on some new headers some web servers can't deal with. Try to reset those flags when testing as well.

Comment: Could you please have a look at chrome developer tools (press F12 on Win) then **Network** tab, and try to run your code. It should display the data you're sending and any errors that would come up, and let us know what's the result. Also try to compare the output on Chrome/Firefox/Chrome incognito

Comment: @Sandro, thanks. It's off though.

Comment: @IvanSatsiuk, I've done that already.

Comment: Check the protocol. if the page url is "https" then the backend code which you are trying to access also should be secured. i have faced similar issue.

Comment: @Jackson, thank you very much! I was mistaken though. The requests are plain HTTP. I'll update my question.

Comment: @Jackson, it turns out that on the problematic environment, the requests are HTTPS/2.0. I'll keep you posted. If this leads somewhere, I'll tell you to post an answer for me to accept. Thanks again.

Comment: Did you noticed that in your second ajax call (post) you use promises, and on the first you use the deprecated methods?

Comment: @MerakMarey, thanks. I had noticed the differences, I did not realize I was using deprecated APIs. However, I don't think that's the cause, because the server is not doing what it's supposed to do. It's not just an issue of not getting a response. I've read that ajax and post are equivalent. The substantial difference is using FormData in one case and form.serialize() on the other. I don't think I can eliminate the FormData though.

Comment: @NSarj Not refering to the ajax and post ...refering to `sucess:` and `.done` ..first one is the old methods for handling responses..second is the recommended one, based on promises...

Comment: Try adding this option:

`async: false`

Comment: @alittlebyte, thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Did that solve the problem?

Comment: @alittlebyte, I haven't been able to reproduce the problem lately. I haven't tried your suggestion after you posted it, but I think I had tried it when the problem first occurred. It had not worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`$.post` is calling `$.ajax` under the covers just defaulting several of the options.

`$.post` defaults `contentType` to `"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"` which would be consistent with your serialized form data payload.

Your call to `$.ajax` sets `contentType` to `false` -- which may cause the browser to send a pre-flight OPTIONS request to the server, which may be causing the difference in behavior you're experiencing.

I would suggest reading the details on `jQuery.ajax()` and the various behaviors based on [options passed here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I need to set the contenttype to false because I'm sending some files. But you're right. And it might have been a cross domain request (due to a DNS redirect). Unfortunately I have no way of knowing now. I will up-vote your answer since it's helpful, but I can't accept it.

Comment: If you're uploading files it'd be best practice to handle that outside the form data postback.